# Laravel deep relations

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I am having some trouble getting some deeps relations.
Basic schema:

An Event can have multiple Shifts.

A Shift has multiple Requirements.

A Requirement has many sollicitations.

In my Event class I have the following code

```
 public function shifts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Shift');
}

public function requirements(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Requirement', 'App\Models\Shift');
}

public function sollicitations(){
    return ???
}
```

This code works as expected, and doesn't throw any errors.

I want a new method 'sollicitations' in the Event class.
This method should return all sollicitations for all the requirements for all the shifts of the event.

How can I go from

```
$this->requirements()-> ???
```

so that I get all the sollicitations?

**Edit**
When i call '$this->requirements', I get a collection of all requirements.
I would like to have the same thing, but for the sollicitations.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function sollicitations($eventID){
    return $this->hasMany('your sollicitations class')->with('requirements')->find($eventID);
}
```

Please change your relation according to your requirement. And Class name ass well in relationship.

Comment: this returns all the events in the database

Comment: Yes with only attach data dependent on it. what do you want?

Comment: I would like to have a collection of all the sollicitations for a specific event

Comment: Does not work sorry, it still returns a collection of events, not one of sollicitations

Comment: Please try again. I am sorry i dint got you question before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83660/discussion-between-jorenv-and-rohitarora).

Comment: I think you should got for join if you have more than two relationships.